# How to get Facebook Unity SDK(version 7.9.4) to work with newly released Unity 5.6.0f3 (64-bit)

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Ok so i'm trying to get the latest version of the facebook unity sdk(v7.9.4) to work with the newly released Unity version 5.6(5.6.0f3).

I created a new 2d project and imported the downloaded facebook sdk unity custom package. Whenever I import the facebook sdk unity custom package, I receive a message from Unity that says the following.

"This Project contains scripts or assemblies that use absolete APIs. If you choose to go ahead, unity will try to upgrade it....blah"

no matter which option i choose, i receive compiler errors and cannot run the example main menu(from the facebook unity sdk examples directory)

too many errors to mention here but try it and see for yourself.

I always try to stay up to date but this is bleeding edge stuff and I'll wait patiently for facebook team or contributors to update. I'm also not sure if I'm receiving these errors because I'm doing something wrong or because the facebook unity sdk does not supports the new version of unity.

Comment: This is because Facebook SDK is already integrated inside Unity 5.6. You can select between 2 versions - 7.9.1 and 7.9.4 which you can select in Player Settings once you switch to the new Facebook platform in Build settings.

Comment: how can i select between the two versions inside unity 5.6? Also, how do i get the example projects from the import to work?

Comment: @Simon_says you still there? I'm lost how to create a facebook gameroom and support facebook login

Comment: https://github.com/fbsamples/friendsmash-unity this sample project shows you integration in Unity. Since Unity 5.6 you don't need to import FB SDK because it's already in the engine. You can select between the two available versions in the Player Settings after you switch on Facebook platform in Unity

Comment: What I had to do is delete the facebook sdk .unitypackage stuff that I imported, and I used the build settings to switch the platform to Facebook (Gameroom Windows) then in the Player Settings, I selected the SDK from the dropdown.